# Sitefinity custom list template embedded image does not display

Tags: sitefinity

I have a custom content module with field(HistoryBody and TestFieldLong) that are long text and required.  In my content widget this field has a rich text editor.  Each content for this type has an image embedded into the field.

This is the custom list template that will be used:

```
@model Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.DynamicContent.Mvc.Models.DynamicContentListViewModel

@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.DynamicContent.WidgetTemplates.Fields.Helpers;
@using Telerik.Sitefinity;
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ContentLinks;
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Helpers;
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Models;
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.DataResolving;
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Model.ContentLinks;
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Pages;

@Html.Script(ScriptRef.JQuery, "top", false)

<h3>Company History</h3>

<div class="@Model.CssClass">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <div class="" @Html.InlineEditingAttributes(Model.ProviderName, Model.ContentType.FullName, (Guid) item.Fields.Id)>
            <h3 class="sf-event-title">@item.Fields.Title</h3>
            &nbsp;@item.Fields.TimelineLabel<br />
            <p @Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("HistoryBody", "LongText")>@Html.Raw(item.Fields.HistoryBody)</p>
            <p @Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("TestFieldLong", "LongText")>@Html.Raw(item.Fields.TestFieldLong)</p>
        </div>
    }


@if (Model.ShowPager)
{
    @Html.Action("Index", "ContentPager", new
    {
        currentPage = Model.CurrentPage,
        totalPagesCount = Model.TotalPagesCount.Value,
        redirectUrlTemplate = ViewBag.RedirectPageUrlTemplate
    })
}
</div>
```

Both LongText fields are configured to use RichText editing...

I place the widget on the page and configure it to use the custom list template shown above and set pagination to show only 1 item on the widget at a time.  So instead of seeing a summary the user will see full information with an image... and can move to different pages to see more info... well thats the plan... however the image does not show.  A place holder appears as if the image could not be found.

I have even tried adding a custom image field into the content but I could not get that to show up through the custom list template either.

Any ideas or pointers on how to get this corrected would be appreciated.

This is Sitefinity v9.x...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resolve links, in your template, you need to use LinkParser.ResolveLinks() method

In your case it should be:

```
<p @Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("HistoryBody", "LongText")>@Html.Raw(LinkParser.ResolveLinks((string)item.Fields.HistoryBody,DynamicLinksParser.GetContentUrl,null,SystemManager.IsInlineEditingMode))</p>
<p @Html.InlineEditingFieldAttributes("TestFieldLong", "LongText")>@Html.Raw(LinkParser.ResolveLinks((string)item.Fields.TestFieldLong,DynamicLinksParser.GetContentUrl,null,SystemManager.IsInlineEditingMode))</p>
```

And this usings:

```
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.GenericContent;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Services;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.Utilities;
```

Comment: I added the usings and tried you mention changes and get the following error: "Cannot use 'GetContentUrl' as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation because it is a method group. Did you intend to invoke the method?" using GetContentUrl....

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention cast to string. Updated my answer